# How to find the number of parameters to a Python function from C?

Tags: python, c

I'm using the Python C API to call Python functions from my application. I'd like to present a list of functions that could be called and would like to be able to limit this list to just the ones with the expected number of parameters.

I'm happy that I can walk the dictionary to extract a list of functions and use `PyCallable_Check` to find out if they're callable, but I'm not sure how I can find out how many parameters each function is expecting?

I've found one technique involving Boost::Python, but would rather not add that for what (I hope!) will be a minor addition.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Okay, so in the end I've discovered how to do it. User-defined Python functions have a member called `func_code` (in Python 3.0+ it's `__code__`), which itself has a member `co_argcount`, which is presumably what Boost::Python extracts in the example given by Christophe.

The code I'm using looks like this (it's heavily based on a documentation example of how to walk a Python dictionary):

```
   PyObject *key, *value;
   int pos = 0;
   while(PyDict_Next(pyDictionary, &pos, &key, &value)) {
      if(PyCallable_Check(value)) {
         PyObject* fc = PyObject_GetAttrString(value, "func_code");
         if(fc) {
            PyObject* ac = PyObject_GetAttrString(fc, "co_argcount");
            if(ac) {
               const int count = PyInt_AsLong(ac);
               // we now have the argument count, do something with this function
               Py_DECREF(ac);
            }
            Py_DECREF(fc);
         }
      }
   }
```

Thanks anyway - that thread did indeed lead me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

[Maybe this is helpful?](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2008-February/013027.html) (not tested, there could be relevant pieces of information along this thread)...

Comment: Am upvoting since there were indeed relevant pieces of information :)

Answer (score 0):

Your C code can call [inspect.getargspec](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=getargspec#inspect.getargspec) just like any Python code would (e.g. via [PyObject_CallMethod](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_callmethod#PyObject_CallMethod) or other equivalent ways) and get all the scoop about the signature of each function or other callable that it may care about.