# Finding python function parameters from C++

Tags: c++, python, parameters

I am calling python functions from C++. I was wondering if it is possible to determine the number of parameters and the names of these parameters. I have read the link [How to find the number of parameters to a Python function from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117164/how-to-find-the-number-of-parameters-to-a-python-function-from-c) however I do not really understand.

I have this C++ function that calls the function 'add' from pyFunction.py. 'add' takes two parameters and returns the sum.

```
static float CallPythonFunc( float *parameters )
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pValue, *pArgs;
    float ret;

    // Initialize the python interpreter
    Py_Initialize();

    // Make sure we are getting the module from the correct place
    // ### This is where we will put the path input
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\"/Developer/IsadoraSDK/IsadoraDemoMathFunction/\")");

    // Build the name object
    // ### This is where we will put the function input
    pName = PyString_FromString("pyFunction");

    // Load the module object
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    // pDict is a borrowed reference
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

    // pFunc is a borrowed reference
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "add");

    //
    // Somehow get the number of arguments and possible the arguments names from 'add'
    //

    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) 
    {       
        // Set the number of arguments
                // This is where I would like to pass in number of arguments
        pArgs = PyTuple_New( 2 /*number of arguments*/ );

        //
        // Instead of the following if I had the arguments I could loop through them
        // and pass the correct number in
        //

        // Argument 1
        pValue = PyFloat_FromDouble((double)parameters[0]);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);

        // Argument 2
        pValue = PyFloat_FromDouble((double)parameters[1]);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pValue);

            // Make the call to the function
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);

        // Set return value
        ret = (float)PyFloat_AsDouble(pValue);

        // Clean up
        Py_DECREF(pArgs);
        Py_DECREF(pValue);
    }

// Clean up
Py_DECREF(pModule);
Py_DECREF(pName);

// Finish the Python Interpreter
Py_Finalize();

return ret;
}
```

I am really not that familiar with C/C++ so any help would be really helpful. Thanks to everyone for their time!

EDIT:
So something like the following?

```
PyObject *tuple, *arglist;
tuple = PyObject_CallMethod(pFunc,"inspect.getargspec","add");
arglist = PyTuple_GetItem(tuple,0);
int size = PyObject_Size(arglist);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This answer to the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117164/how-to-find-the-number-of-parameters-to-a-python-function-from-c/1117518#1117518) seems to be what you want. `inspect.getargspec` does exactly what you want on the Python side, and as the answer states, you can use [PyObject_CallMethod](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_callmethod#PyObject_CallMethod) or one of the related functions described at that link target to call `inspect.getargspec` from your C++ code, get the returned tuple as a `PyObject`, use `PyTuple_GetItem(returned_tuple, 0)` to get the argument list, and then use either `PyObject_Size()` or `PyObject_Length()` on the list to get the number of arguments. You'll also want to check the second and third elements of the returned tuple and increment the number of arguments by 1 for each of the two that is not `Py_None`. See the below code snippet for why.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def testfunc(a, b, c, *d, **e):
    pass

>>> inspect.getargspec(testfunc)
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs='d', keywords='e', defaults=None)
```

---

Here's an example of what you should do (not all possible errors may be checked for, but it should be all of the NULL checks that may be necessary):

```
PyObject *pName, *pInspect, *argspec_tuple, *arglist;
int size;

pName = PyString_FromString("inspect");

if (pName)
{
    pInspect = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);


    if (pInspect)
    {
        pName = PyString_FromString("getargspec");

        if (pName)
        {
            argspec_tuple = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(pInspect, pName, pFunc, NULL);
            Py_DECREF(pName);

            if (argspec_tuple)
            {
                arglist = PyTuple_GetItem(argspec_tuple, 0);

                if (arglist)
                {
                    size = PyObject_Size(arglist)
                         + (PyTuple_GetItem(argspec_tuple, 1) == Py_None ? 0 : 1)
                         + (PyTuple_GetItem(argspec_tuple, 2) == Py_None ? 0 : 1);  // Haven't actually tested this, but it should work
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I also edited my post for a follow up question

Comment: In addition to what you put in your edit, you'd want to include something like `size += (PyTuple_GetItem(tuple, 1) == Py_None ? 0 : 1) + (PyTuple_GetItem(tuple, 2) == Py_None ? 0 : 1);` to account for the possibility of `*` and `**` arguments. (If you don't recognize the syntax used, it's called the ternary operator and is similar to an in-line `if...else` statement.)

Comment: Oh, actually, check my updated answer for what you might want to do.

Comment: Oh, just noticed as well that in Python 3+, you'd want to use `getfullargspec` rather than `getargspec`, as the latter is deprecated since version 3.0. The syntax wouldn't change here due to the starting elements of the tuple returned by `getfullargspec` being the same as the elements of the tuple returned by `getargspec`, but this is especially important if your Python function has keyword-only arguments or annotations, as `getargspec` fails when used on a function with such. This also means you'd need to check for such arguments the same way you checked the size of the normal argument list.