# finding out how many arguments a PyObject method needs

Tags: python, python-c-api, pyobject

We can extract a PyObject pointing to a python method using

```
PyObject *method = PyDict_GetItemString(methodsDictionary,methodName.c_str());
```

I want to know how many arguments the method takes. So if the function is

```
def f(x,y):
    return x+y
```

how do I find out it needs 2 arguments?

Comment: Potentially relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616398/finding-python-function-parameters-from-c

Comment: Also, just noticed the `.c_str()` in there - so I'm guessing you're using C++. Have you looked at the Boost.Python or other wrapper libraries? - using the native Python C-API is not the most pleasant experience

Answer (score 0):

Followed through the link provided by Jon.  Assuming you don't want to (or can't) use Boost in your application, the following should get you the number (easily adapted from [How to find the number of parameters to a Python function from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117164/how-to-find-the-number-of-parameters-to-a-python-function-from-c)):

```
PyObject *key, *value;
int pos = 0;
while(PyDict_Next(methodsDictionary, &pos, &key, &value)) {
    if(PyCallable_Check(value)) {
        PyObject* fc = PyObject_GetAttrString(value, "func_code");
        if(fc) {
            PyObject* ac = PyObject_GetAttrString(fc, "co_argcount");
            if(ac) {
               const int count = PyInt_AsLong(ac);
               // we now have the argument count, do something with this function
               Py_DECREF(ac);
            }
            Py_DECREF(fc);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're in Python 2.x the above definitely works.  In Python 3.0+, you seem to need to use `"__code__"` instead of `"func_code"` in the snippet above.

I appreciate the inability to use Boost (my company won't allow it for the projects I've been working on lately), but in general, I would try to knuckle down and use that if you can, as I've found that the Python C API can in general get a bit fiddly as you try to do complicated stuff like this.